# Assimp Compile error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, assimp

Halo
I have use CMaker to make the assimp 3.3.1 to be sln.
However, when the VS2015 compile it, it becomes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHnU9.png)

Please help me. I need the assimp.lib and dll work.

Comment: Is that the problem from Assimp?

Answer (score -1):

In the solution explorer, observe that there exists an "ALL_BUILD" entry as well as one named after your project. Right click on your project name, click on "set as StartUp project", and hit run.

Answer (score -1):

Download cmake gui from this site https://cmake.org/download/.

1. Open cmake gui as administrator
2. Select folder of the assimp source. (Browse the source),
3. Browse Build (Optional)
4. Click Generate and wait.
5. After finish, click Open Project.

Nb. Don't forget select current generator for c compiler. I use visual studio 14 - (2015)